# control values on refresh

Tags: asp.net, refresh

I have set an asp.net page to refresh every after sometime. The problem is that once the page is refresh, the state of the controls are lost, like the dropdown loses all its item. I checked the viewstate property of the controls but they are set to be enabled. Any idea why is it so?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a web form is also an HTML form. You need to POST the form instead of refreshing.